# Sharing state between two components of a single route

Tags: reactjs, react-router

My router looks like this:

```js
<Router>
  <Route path="/" component={Page}>
    // ...
    <Route
      path=":id"
      components={{ menu: ResourceMenu, content: Resource }}
    >
      <Route
        path="foo"
        component={ResourceFoo}
      />
      <Route
        path="bar"
        component={ResourceBar}
      />
      // ...
    </Route>
    // ...
  </Route>
</Router>
```

`Page` component has slots for `menu` and `content`, located in completely different parts of the markup. There's no way to merge them.

`ResourceFoo`, `ResourceBar` and others get mounted as children of `Resource`. While they're at it, `Resource` also passes some props to them, which are retrieved from an API.

The problem is, `ResourceMenu` depends on all the same backend resources as `Resource`, and right now they're both making their own API requests. Code duplication can be dealt with, to some extent, but I don't have any proper caching [yet], so the client ends up making redundant requests.

How can I wrap `Resource` and `ResourceMenu` in one parent (or somehow put `ResourceMenu` inside `Resource`), while still being able to fill `Page`'s slots? Or is there some radically different approach I'm not aware of?

Comment: i face with similar problem right now. We cant render components partially in react router. I am writing my own route handler which manages states instead of components. So i can control component visibility and other properties even they are nested. You can control your Resource components even they are not wrapped together with this way i think.

Comment: @muratgozel What exactly are you doing? You're still using React Router, right? And one of your upper-level components (like `Page` in my example) is some special component, which does all the heavy lifting for its children, and then just passes down props?

Comment: That's right but i dont use react router. I only use history package. When you clicked a link inside of any component, a click handler function decides how states should change. Click handler also change the browser url by simple `history.push("/foo")` command. In your situation, like you said, `Page` component should have a function that defines states or props according to url path. Whenever url changes, that function will give you changed states and your `Resource` and `Resource Menu` will be updated from one single source automatically.

Comment: I dont know if this is a clear solution for your situation but i am sure about one thing: loading pages with react router like loading different html pages every click. i think updating states in every click is more react way. unfortunately i cant share my code because its under heavy development:)

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid using the `components` property on the route. It feels like you could accomplish what you need with a simple layout. Lets say Page has a menu and content section, the ResourceFoo and ResourceBar could both use these and simply pass them the props as follows:

https://gist.github.com/marr/36cdbe52acd38de9045e

I may be over-simplifying things, but it seems like you have standard routes and can use the above structure.